# elasticsearch aggregation PHP

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to get the unique values from my elasticsearch database.

So i want the unique names from my elasticsearch database.

So i am aggregation like so ---

```
   $paramss = [
            'index' => 'myIndex',
            'type' => 'myType',
            'ignore_unavailable' => true,
            'ignore' => [404, 500]
        ];


    $paramss['body'] = <<<JSON
{
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "langs" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name" }
    }
}}
JSON;

        $results = $client->search($paramss);
        print_r(json_encode($results));
```

i get the result like so---

```
{
took: 3,
timed_out: false,
_shards: {
    total: 5,
    successful: 5,
    failed: 0
},
hits: {
    total: 1852,
    max_score: 0,
    hits: [

    ]
},
aggregations: {
    langs: {
        buckets: [
            {
                key: "aaaa.se",
                doc_count: 430
            },
            {
                key: "bbbb.se",
                doc_count: 358
            },
            {
                key: "cccc.se",
                doc_count: 49
            },
            {
                key: "eeee.com",
                doc_count: 46
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

But the problem is i am not getting all the unique values, I am getting only **10 values**, which is default value for elasticsearch query.

So how can i change the query size !!!

i tried like so---

```
   $paramss = [
            'index' => 'myIndex',
            'type' => 'myType',
            'size' => 1000,
            'ignore_unavailable' => true,
            'ignore' => [404, 500]
        ];
```

which returns me some weird documents.

So do anyone knows the solution of this problem.

How can i get all the unique names from my elasticsearch database, can someone help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are also doing everuthing right, except you the `size`.

The `"size": 0` should come after the targeted field's name.

```
$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
    $query['body'] = '{
        "aggs" : {
            "all_sources" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "source",
                    "order" : { "_term" : "asc" },
                    "size": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put size parameter inside terms:

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "langs" : {
        "terms" : { 
            "field" : "name",
            "size": 0
        }
    }
}}
```

Link to documentation where you can find more info:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: No, you didn't. You have size parameter on the same level as aggs.

Comment: why this answer is down voted. This is exactly correct answer. You have to define a size = 0 inside your aggregations otherwise ES will aggregate only top 20 of result set.